# Google Search On Screen does not work

Tags: google, permissions, google-search, google-assistant

I have the following problem: when I long-tap home button, a Google Now with search field appears, instead of Search on screen. I've tried to grant all perms to allow it use screen contents, but nothing changes.

I use Xiaomi Redmi 4x with AOSP Extended.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you need is called **Now on Tap**.

According to [Google blog](https://search.googleblog.com/2015/12/make-your-holidays-little-easier-with.html), Now on Tap is available only in English, French, German, Spanish, Italian, Russian and Korean. All you have to do is set one of those as a secondary language in your phone settings to make it work.

Comment: I did, English is my primary (on phone, not IRL) language. But still, nothing changes.

Comment: I've been playing a bit with this and I could get it working only when English was my **second** language :c
Maybe Google wants us to use Google Assistant instead?

Comment: Well, I don't mind as long as they satisfy my needs. Yet they don't.